# How do I make a Spree API service call from an AngularJS application?

Tags: angularjs, spree

I want to use the Spree API to build a completely custom frontend for Spree using AngularJS and Bootstrap. I am not sure how to do that or where to start. Is there any document which I can read up that could help me. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's a link to the Spree API docs: https://guides.spreecommerce.com/api/

Comment: You can use the $http component in the Anjular. refer a link https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/